# Remove a sublist if all the elements are 0

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have this list

```
lst = [ [2,0,1], [0,0,0], [3,2,4], [0,0,0,0] ]
```

I'm looking for a way to remove those lists that only have numbers 0

So the expected output is:

```
lst = [ [2,0,1], [3,2,4] ]
```

Comment: best way I think would be to loop through each sublist and remove all zeros. If you're left with an empty sublist, remove that. You're going to need to provide some "what I've tried" for actual help.

Comment: What do you mean by "an automatic way"? Nothing is automatic: you have to write algorithms in order to do stuff.

Comment: `list(filter(any, lst))` is an amusing way, if your lists only have ints.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension and any:

```
[l for l in lst if any(l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this list comprehension

```
[l for l in lst if not all(x == 0 for x in l)]
```